# no viable conversion from returned value of type bankAccount to function return type int

Tags: c++

So, I'm building a project and am getting errors:

> `no viable conversion from returned value of type bankAccount to function return type int`
>       `|111|error: invalid operands to binary expression ('bankAccount' and 'int')|`

```
int bankAccount::searchfor(bankAccount lists[], int length, int acctNum)
{

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if(lists[i] == acctNum)
    {
        return lists[i];
    }
    else
        return -1;
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bankAccount::searchfor`, the return type of the function is `int`, but returns a `lists[i]`, which has type `bankAccount`.

As a guess, you meant to return `i` instead:

```
int
bankAccount::searchfor(bankAccount lists[], int length, int acctNum) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(lists[i] == acctNum) {
            return i;
        } else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

However, it seems you mean to return `i` if the `acctNum` is found, and `-1` otherwise. So, move the `return -1` to be what is returned if the loop ends without finding the `acctNum`.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(lists[i] == acctNum) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```